# Access denied page in Sitecore when using requireLogin

Tags: security, authentication, login

Our current site (Sitecore 9.1) configuration looks like this: (simplified for readability)

```
<site name="the-website" patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']"
            language="en"
...                
            loginPage="/auth/login"
            requireLogin="true" />
```

We want to redirect unauthenticated users to an `Access denied` page. The `Access denied` page should exist in Sitecore, such that editors can configure its look-and-feel. If possible we would like to not configure Sitecore access rights.

Is it possible to use requireLogin for the entire site except for some specific pages?(like access denied)

This is for extranet users.

Comment: This is for extranet user?

Comment: Yes sorry for being unclear

Comment: Hos I have rolled back your question to the original question posted. If you have further questions, they need to be opened separately, not appended on to the original, otherwise the answer that @MarkCassidy gave below doesn't make sense in the context of the question. If Marks answer, answers the question above, please accept it and open your extra questions as new posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you need to configure `loginPage` but set `requireLogin` to false.

Your next step will be to remove the access for `Everyone` on your `/sitecore/content/site` node and `Remove Inheritance`. You then need to create a new role, "Authenticated Users" which will get the access from this level down instead.

Finally you need to re-allow `Everyone` into the few pages you require. The error page and so on.

Brian Pedersen has a good writeup here: [Sitecore: Login to website and how to restrict access to content](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2017/11/24/sitecore-login-to-website-and-how-to-restrict-access-to-content/)

Your core problem is; if you set `requireLogin` to `true` like you suggest, Sitecore is always going to force a login. From anyone. Error pages or not.

Comment: Almost there. I updated the original question with some additional information. Now I am getting "Permission to the requested document was denied"

Comment: Actually I am not sure if the information I added to the question, qualifies for a new question? If so, I will accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: I didn't give a comment, I gave an answer. And polymorphic questions is a particularly nasty habit. Your amendment is a new question.